# Python get url from string(regex)

Tags: python

So what I am trying to do is to extract all urls from HTTP requests list. They should be stripped of protocol, parameters and slash at the end of the path(if exists).So for example:

```
10.4.180.222 [5/Feb/2018:08:03:40 +0100] "GET http://somewebsite.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1080
10.4.180.222 [5/Feb/2018:08:03:11 +0100] "GET http://www.somewebsite.cc/somesubdomain/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3056
10.4.180.222 [5/Feb/2018:08:03:11 +0100] "GET https://www.somewebsite.ua HTTP/1.1" 200 3056
```

Should be:

```
somewebsite.com
www.somewebsite.cc/somepath
www.somewebsite.ua
```

I've tried to do this in two steps, without using any sophisticated regex(just general for any url)

```
urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', file.read())
```

And then using urlparse.

```
domain = '{url.netloc}{url.path}'.format(url=urlparse(url))
```

It works almost fine. However I am getting path ending with slash.

```
www.somewebsite.cc/somepath/
```

So I've decided to use regex. However, I know only basics so I can't come up with anything well-functioning.Right now I have something like that but it doesn't cover "/" thing and different protocols :/

Thank you for any advice :)

```
((?:www\.+)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-]*))
```

Comment: Why don't you split your strings on whitespace? That would be much easier.

Comment: If you know the format of your input string isn't going to change, then splitting it on whitespace to retrieve the url string and passing it to `urlparse()` to get out the components you want (and cleaning up trailing slashes with `.strip('/')`) would be a lot clearer as opposed to doing it all in one big regex pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the end slash is your only problem, this is the solution.

```
urls = [ x.rstrip('/') for x in re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', file.read()) ]
```

In other words, just do

> urls = [ x.rstrip('/') for x in ***< your regex goes here >*** ].

Comment: Or you could add `?(?=/?(?:\s|$))` to the end of that regex pattern so the trailing `/` isn't consumed.